# Wget command does not download the github repository, "Not a directory" error?

Tags: github, wget

I need to download the contents of this page: https://github.com/kata-containers/packaging/tree/master/kernel

Unfortunately, :

```
wget https://github.com/kata-containers/packaging/tree/master/kernel
```

is not working. It downloads something called 'kernel' and then when I do 'cd kernel' I get "-bash: cd: kernel: Not a directory."

Why is wget not downloading the contents of the directory?

Comment: That `kernel` _resource_ is not a directory.  It's an HTML document that happens to present, among other things, a hierarchy of links corresponding to the `kernel` directory in that repository.  I'm not familiar with anything more than basic `wget` usage, but it's not going to know how (automatically, anyways) to give you a local copy of that remote directory tree like you're hoping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"kernel" is the HTML file for the page you are looking at. You can download the entire repo at https://github.com/kata-containers/packaging/archive/master.zip and peruse the kernel subfolder.

Comment: Ahh thank you. How did you know how to locate this link? I've been trying to figure this out for so long but I don't get how it works.

Comment: @programmer12 You need to go to [the page for the root of the repository](https://github.com/kata-containers/packaging) and then click the green "Code" link.

Comment: Ah okay thank you. Also I think this is a stupid question, but how can we tell that /packaging is the root of the repo?

Comment: In the first set of breadcrumb links I clicked the leftmost link, `kata-containers`, and that took me to an organization page; therefore, the next link, `packaging`, must be the repository root. Alternatively, in the second set of breadcrumb links, `packaging` is the leftmost (shallowest) directory listed, and those links don't appear on the root directory page. Otherwise, you could always click the `..` link in each directory listing until you reach a directory with no parent. The quickest way might be to click the `Code` tab (even if already highlighted) to get to the repository root.